# Python - Extract private variables from a function?

Tags: python, function, scipy

I have a function f2(a, b)

It is only ever called by a minimize algorithm which iterates the function for different values of a and b each time.  I would like to store these iterations in excel for plotting.

Is it possible to extract these values (i only need to paste them all into excel or a text file)  easily?  Conventional return and print won't work within f2.  Is there any way to extract the values a and b to a public list in the main body some other way?

The algorithm may iterate dozens or hundreds of times.

So far I have tried:

- Print to console (can't paste this data into excel easily)
- Write to file (csv) within f2, the csv file gets overwritten within the function each time though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the values to a global list.

```
values = []
def f2(a,b):
    values.append((a,b))
    #todo: actual function logic goes here
```

Then you can look at `values` in the main scope once you're done iterating.

Answer (score 1):

> Write to file (csv) within f2, the csv file gets overwritten within the function each time though.

Not if you open the file in append mode:

```
with open("file.csv", "a") as myfile:
```